# taxify like pin on map "swift

Tags: swift, google-maps

I have tried the search query above on Bing and Google but got nothing close to my need.

How do implement the taxify/Uber like Pin dropped in the middle of the Google map and obtain location info as the user moves around using swift?

Thanks for your usual support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the pin as any imageView in the middle of the google map (Above it) , and obtain new center location when user drags the map with

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didChange position: GMSCameraPosition) {

    print("\(position.target.latitude),\(position.target.longitude)")

}

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, idleAt position: GMSCameraPosition) {

    print("\(position.target.latitude),\(position.target.longitude)")
}
```